# VScode wont let me select cygwin python3 interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, cygwin

When selecting a python interpreter in VScode I navigate to C:\cgywin64\python3.8.exe and VScode allows me to select this file, but after choosing it VScode continues to tell me I need to select a Python interpreter. However, choosing C:\cygwin\python2.7.exe does work.

I belive VSCode is up to date (not exactly sure how to check).

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.3

python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

Anyone have a similar issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run python3 in the cmd window to check whether it can be used normally, if it works, then you could try the following:

1. Check python environment variables, refer to: [environment variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_environment.htm).
2. Check the python path setting in VSCode, refer to:[pythonPath](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter).
3. Try to create a virtual environment and check whether you could use python3 successfully. Reference: [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments).

If it still doesn't work, providing more relevant setting information will solve it better.